# JSX Graph: Event for polygon borders get dragged

Tags: javascript, events, jsxgraph

I need to catch events that change polygon's position. It's ok for points and a polygon itself:

```
polygon.on('drag', handler);
pointOfPolygon.on('drag', handler);
```

But these don't catch it when the polygon is dragged by its border. How can that be achieved?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polygon's borders can be accessed through the array `polygon.border`, whose elements can handle the drag event. Thus, an elementary example would be:

```
var cnt = 0;
var pol = board.create('polygon', [[-2, -2], [2, -1], [1, 3]]);
var txt = board.create('text', [2, 3, "Text"]);

var handler = function(evt) {
        cnt++;
        txt.setText(cnt);
    };

pol.borders[0].on('drag', handler);
pol.borders[1].on('drag', handler);
pol.borders[2].on('drag', handler);
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/125nfxL7/1/